# Pydev pep8 checking with custom pep8.py (with name checking support), seems to break

Tags: python, pydev

I want to use this PEP8 module that has name checking support...
https://github.com/posborne/pep8

However when I select this, nothing happens, NO pep8 checking happens.

Can I do anything?

Pydev version 2.4

Answer (score 2):

I spent some time trying to debug this. I don't know much about PyDev nor Java, but it would seem that:

- PyDev is trying to parse pep8.py using it's own Jython implementation instead of local Python's one (probably they want to make it faster this way). Jython (at least the one I have) cannot parse the "yield" keyword, that's why newer versions of pep8.py don't work.
- The older versions don't work either, because PyDev requires some custom-tailored signatures of pep8.py's methods which were not marged into the main stream.

I ended up making [this simple Eclipse plugin](https://github.com/wrygiel/eclipse-external-problem-marker). I was able to connect latest version of pep8.py with my editors. Hope it helps someone ;)

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you've enabled pep8 checking and you're setting that file in window > preferences > code analysis > pep8.py > location of pep8.py?

If that is the case, it could be because of some bugfixes which were done in the internal version of PyDev (to work under the PyDev internal Jython 2.1 version)... those were already contributed back to pep8.py, but maybe were not integrated in that branch? (i.e.: pull request: https://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8/pull/49)

If that custom module did something else that doesn't work on Jython 2.1, that'd explain it too.

If that's the case, the proper solution would be fixing that pep8 module to work under Jython 2.1...

Now, if it's something else entirely... Do you have some error in your error log?

Comment: I have a similar issue. I tried many versions of pep8 (including the current git master), none worked. I got various errors in the error log (like "TypeError: __init__() too many arguments; expected 3 got 4" or "SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('D:\\...\\pep8.py', 309, 19, 'yield 0, "E304 blank lines found after function decorator"\n '))"). I am still trying to debug this, but I'm running out of ideas how to grasp it.

Comment: Actually, I just saw that the current version of pep8 is no longer compatible with the internal Jython version that PyDev uses, so, you MUST use the pep8.py version that's shipped with PyDev (in the latest versions at least). It's located at: plugins\org.python.pydev\pysrc\third_party\pep8\pep8.py

Comment: BTW, I needed the latest version of pep8 too, so I made a simple plugin, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578941/integrating-external-highlighter-tool-in-eclipse-editor (I also added the link to my response)

Comment: Nice way to integrate your external checker :)