# Integrating external highlighter tool in Eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Okay, this is probably easy, but I don't know proper words to describe it, and hence, google it...

I have an external script which **takes a file name** and outputs this:

```
/path/to/file.py:683:80: E501 line too long (85 characters)
/path/to/file.py:690:21: other error message
..etc..
```

Now, I know **this output format is widely accepted** by other, much simple IDEs, e.g. EditPlus. I don't know how to integrate it with Eclipse though.

I want this script integrated with my editor windows. I want Eclipse to run it in the background, every time I save the file, and then parse the results and mark all the lines which occured in the script's output. It should look something like this:

[image: Example]

How can I do that?

*Note (for those who know why I need this):* I know PyDev has a pep8.py checker integrated, but it's not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I implemented that plugin myself. I does exactly what I asked for, I guess. I made it configurable with some rude regular expressions.

I posted the code and installation instructions [here](https://github.com/wrygiel/eclipse-external-problem-marker) (GitHub).

Comment: thank you so so much. Your Plugin is awsome, you saved my day :-). Just in case anyone needs it, the correct command for starting pep8 in linux is <value>python /usr/local/bin/pep8 $1</value>

Answer (score 0):

Your own plug-in that runs the script and examines its output can create Markers from that output.  See http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html .

Comment: I'm aware of this option, but it's still hard to believe that no such plugin already exists. I was quite sure this kind of output is really "the standard". All compilers throw out this stuff.